# I want to model a voltage source proportional to the frequency in LTspice

Tags: voltage, frequency, spice

Is it possible to make a function for a voltage source that is equal to
V = kf where k is an arbitrary constant?

Is there a spice component that can achieve the same result?

I am doing this to model the voltage induced in a search coil by an external magnetic field. I want to make a bode plot. I am expecting that a higher frequency will result in a higher gain when I simulate it.

[image]

Comment: How do you propose that would work, in the time domain?

Comment: Useful search term : frequency to voltage converter

Comment: look up behavioral voltage source. And you might want to show a schematic of what you are simulating to make things clearer.

Comment: Where does the parameter `f` come from in your simulation? How can there be a frequency of operation without another source?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the f is representing whatever the frequency will be when I am making a bode plot.

Comment: @pat Thanks, I did look up behavioral voltage sources but I don't believe I can conduct bode analysis with them

Comment: The frequency range of your bode plot is irrelevant. You can ask for a plot for a frequency range where you have no simulation data. The question is how are you going to control the frequency for your simulation?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/583954/95619)? The answers in there are very much valid here.

Answer (score 1):

Drive a fixed amplitude AC current source into an inductor, the voltage is \$j\omega L i\$, then use an ideal voltage buffer or VCVS.

With your edit showing that you are trying to model the voltage induced in an inductor from a fixed amplitude oscillating magnetic field, this model actually has a physical interpretation.  If the magnetic field is being generated by a current \$i\$ flowing in another conductor, then the \$L\$ above is the mutual inductance between the that external conductor and your search coil.

**Edit in response to comment:**

This is the configuration I was trying to describe:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHNSq6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am trying to simulate but as a current source can't be an input to a ideal opamp (infinite input impedance) i am getting this error. Analysis failed Matrix is singular. See question to see the diagram

Comment: See edit above -

Comment: Thank you so much. This works like a charm. I can't upvote because I don't have enough privledges